# split one column into two or more columns in sql

Tags: sql

**PASS_SHORT_DESC** - Column name

```
DMM-SAH
JED-SAH
RUH-SAH
DMM-DAM
DMM-ISB
DMM-KHI
DMM-LHE
AQI-KHI
JED-ISM
JED-KHI
RUH-ISB
YNB-ISM
```

how to split one column into two column:

I need this output:

```
From:         TO:
DMM          SAH
JED          SAH
RUH          ISB
YNB          ISM
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

On speculation that you are using MySQL, you may use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PASS_SHORT_DESC, '-', 1) AS `From:`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PASS_SHORT_DESC, '-', -1) AS `TO:`
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in case you are using SQLServer, you may use a select like this

```
select SUBSTRING(PASS_SHORT_DESC,1,charindex('-',PASS_SHORT_DESC)-1) as [from:],
       SUBSTRING(PASS_SHORT_DESC,charindex('-',PASS_SHORT_DESC)+1,LEN(PASS_SHORT_DESC))  as [to:]
from exampleTable
```

I should'nt use a [From:] as column name, it can only cause problem with SQL sentences due to FROM is a reserved word.